# Проблема слитного текста в консоле eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Я только начинаю программировать и столкнулся с проблемой вывода текста , все слова или символы выводятся слитно в консоле вот пример:

````
      public class practice6 {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
        int fulltime=200;
        int hour,minutes;
        hour=fulltime/60;
        minutes=fulltime%60;
        System.out.println("fulltime=" +hour+ "hour and"+ minutes +"minutes.");
}
}```
вот что показывает консоль : fulltime=3hour and20minutes.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемы с Eclipse, я не вижу, дума проблема в программе, Вы не поставили пробелы в коде

```
System.out.println("fulltime = " + hour + " hour and" + minutes + " minutes.");
```

Вывод:
`fulltime = 3 hour and 20 minutes.`

Comment: Попробовал ваше решения , не помогло проблема осталась.

Comment: @Олег как оно могло не помочь) скиньте что выводится

Comment: fulltime = 3hour and20minutes.

Comment: System.out.println("fulltime = " +hour+ " hour and "+ minutes +" minutes.");

Comment: @Олег напишите как я выше указал. Вы сами вольны добавлять пробелы куда надо. Они не с потолка берутся

Comment: System.out.println("fulltime = " + hour + "hour and" + minutes + "minutes."); вот так написал но вывод на консоль прежний.

Comment: @Олег Вы же не так копируете, что я вам в комментах написал. Вот . Просто скопируйте : 
System.out.println("fulltime = " +hour+ " hour and "+ minutes +" minutes.");

Comment: @AVRamones, Большое спасибо ,теперь увидел разницу).

Comment: @Олег ну  и славно)